# Is it possible to put a user control into a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contextmenu

I don't know if this is possible but does anyone know if there is a way to put a user control inside a context menu, I have a dialog for adding items to a list but I would like when I click the add button for the control to be displayed in the context menu instead. (dont like having a lot of dialog's in my app).

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
<Button  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem>
                <vm:MyControlView/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? (or something similar)

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: crashes when button is loaded

Comment: What's the crash? What's the call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7df91272-1144-4cdd-b446-af6b356af183), it looks like you might be able to extend ContextMenu like John Dunn did to meet your needs.